# How to include python code on a website (HTMl)?

Tags: python, html, frontend

I have a python script that uses modules (beautiful soup, openpyxl, etc) and I want to either convert it to a front-end language with some type of online converter or figure out how to embed it into my HTML code. Does anyone have any ideas??

Comment: To work with python on the web, you'll need to make a server using python. Take a look at Flask to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Brython](https://brython.info/) in your HTML. It is a Python compiler written in Javascript that allows you to put a Python script in your HTML for client-side execution.